# Função de Javascript não resume $_POST do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Estou implementando uma barra de progresso numa script simples de upload de arquivo. Tenho os três arquivos que estão me dando dor de cabeça, `Upload.php` onde está situado a script de upload, `script.js` onde está situado a script que atualiza a barra de progress e finalmente o `index.php` onde está a form do upload.

O painel de upload é um `form` que envia com o `$_POST` o trigger para o arquivo do PHP, e sempre funcionou certinho, depois que implementei essa script (`script.php`) começou a dar problema, **a barra de progresso funciona, mas é acionado a script de upload em PHP**.

### index.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="pic" />
     <!-- ........ -->
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">Upload file</button> <!-- botão de upload -->

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<!--scripts include-->

<!-- jQuery Library-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Form Plug in -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<!-- our main javascript file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

### script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* variables */
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var bar = $('.bar');

    /* submit form with ajax request */
    $('form').ajaxForm({

        /* set data type json */
        dataType:  'json',

        /* reset before submitting */
        beforeSend: function() {
            bar.width('0%');
            percent.html('0%');
        },

        /* progress bar call back*/
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var pVel = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(pVel);
            percent.html(pVel);
        },

    });
});
```

### upload.php

[(Ver arquivo completo)](http://pastebin.com/dy182bbE)

```
// muitas funções que uso na função abaixo
//
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{
    $original = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
    $array = explode('.', $original);
```

Então, por resumo, o problema é causado quando clico no botão de fazer upload, a barra de progresso anda, mas o arquivo não é enviado, pois a função de upload de PHP não é chamada.

> Já tentei colocar um `echo 'debug';` no arquivo `upload.php` para ver se pelo menos a função era chamada, mas não apareceu nada na página.

Comment: Tem como você passar o arquivo upload.php completo?

Comment: Pergunta atualizada.

Comment: Mas o form ta sem action, e pelo que eu vi, nenhuma requisição AJAX é feita pro upload.php. Como o HTML vai saber pra onde mandar esse formulário?

Comment: o botão `btn-upload` no form vai gerar um evento no `Post`, eu sou iniciante em PHP/HTML, pelo que sei, é isso o que acontece no código, sempre funcionou.

Comment: Faz o seguinte no action do form coloca action="caminho do arquivo upload.php"

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso, ele redireciona a página e mostra apenas que o arquivo enviou, mas a página inicial `index.php` some...

Answer (score 0):

Não consegui encontrar no seu código jquery a string com a URL que aponta para o arquivo uploads.php. isso é necessário se não por default ele envia para mesma página do formulário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça esse alteração pra ver o resultado.